# Child born in UK to Indonesian citizens

Tags: united-kingdom, passport, children

My wife and I are both Indonesian nationals, currently living in the UK on a Tier 2 Visa.

We had a baby born in the UK recently. He has a birth certificate and no passport. How do we get him a permission to stay in the UK?

Comment: Are you or your wife "settled" in the UK?

Comment: @user102008, we have lived in the UK for one year. Our visa run out in two years. We do not have indefinite leave to remain.

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8375/visa-for-baby-born-in-uk-parents-on-tier-2-visa/8376

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being born in the UK is generally not enough to satisfy the UK citizenship requirements. From the information you have provided, your son will likely not qualify. You will need to apply for a tier 2 dependent visa for your son. The application will require your son to have a valid passport. My understanding of the UKBA rules are that you do not need to apply immediately for the dependent visa. However, your son will need the dependent visa to renter the UK if he has to leave the country for an emergency.

Comment: To re-enter, visa notwithstanding, he will need a passport anyway...

Comment: Does he need a visa if we all only leave UK after my visa runs out?

Comment: @adipro you do not need a visa to leave the UK. You only need the visa to enter the UK. You generally need a passport, and potentially a visa, to enter a country.

Comment: This answer is not accurate anymore on several points, e.g. I have applied for my baby’s visa prior to getting a passport. See a more recent question: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8375/visa-for-baby-born-in-uk-parents-on-tier-2-visa/8376