# NHS treatment for baby born in the UK staying without visa and costs involved

Tags: united-kingdom, nhs

We are on a Tier 2 visa. We are expecting a baby in February next year. We are not intending to travel anywhere until my husband gets an ILR December next year.

My questions are:

- Do we need to get a visa for our child?
- If a visa is not required, how can a baby get treatment from NHS after the initial 3 months?
- What are the costs involved after the initial 3-month period? Is it billed at 150% of the private treatment costs at the GP?

Comment: Welcome to expats.se. Please take a look at our [help]. I think this is a duplicate of https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8375/visa-for-baby-born-in-uk-parents-on-tier-2-visa although a question focused on NHS treatment after 3 months would be useful.

Comment: What nationality will the child be? And will the baby be habitually resident in the U.K.? If so, it should be eligible for NHS treatment on the same basis as any other U.K. resident.

Answer (score 1):

No visa is required for the child. After 3 months the child can still get treatment from the NHS, but you wil be required to pay the costs yourself at 150% costs. Vaccinations are still free.

[Chapter 1 of the "Guidance on implementing the overseas visitor hospital charging regulations 2015"](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-overseas-visitors-hospital-charging-regulations)

> 1.2.
>
> Those who have paid the health surcharge or are covered by transitional 
>   arrangements
>
> Non-EEA nationals, who are subject to immigration control, are exempt from 
>   charge 
>   if one of the following applies to them while their leave to 
>   enter/remain is valid:
>
> - they have paid the surcharge;
> - .
>     .
>     .
> - A child born in the UK to an above mentioned exempt person is also exempt 
>     from charge up
>     to the age of three months provided that the child has not left 
>     the UK since birth